# How to handle multiple views

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to develop a multi view application while trying to avoid navigation controllers as apple recommend this for the iPad.

My problem is nav controllers are the only way I know how to make a multiview app, does anyone have a link to code or a book I could look at that show other ways? I already have exploring the iphone sdk and the developers cook book but both focus on nav controllers.

What others ways are there to link screens?

I have an initial login screen and then a main menu section where the user can choose from a list of options, how should I implement this. Please give an example as I can't seemt to code things from my head yet.

I feel like I'm going crazy trying to get over this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest running through the iPhone View Controller Program Guide, I had similar questions last week I was mulling over and discovered various solutions to the problem here using Custom View Controllers and.or Combined View Controller interfaces.

I don't have an example, but through custom code you'll be able to control which view shows when.  The [Custom View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW31) section has a diagram which describes what you're likely trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you don't want to use the NavigationViewController approach. It gives you a lot of benefits.

But I would load the main menu view on startup and show your login screen as a modal view instantly (above it). When the user logged in correctly you may dismiss the modal view and your main menu will appear.

Comment: Because Apple prefers `UISplitViewController` on the iPad.